# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken rails 5

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm using rails version - `5.0.0.1`

I used `form_for` to create a form

```
<%= form_for :session,:action => '/login/authenicate/',:remote => true, :authenticity_token => true, :html => { :class => 'validate', :id => 'form_login' } do |s| %>
```

I am using ajax to send the request to the server.

This is the form that is displayed in the browser.

```
<form class="validate" id="form_login" action="/login" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="i3GVfaN2PbZ80JvdSqO921GuNLaxxo9ctsTBE21aYJYo/XtBG7lyqU7xAzoFjClwOGWSCrC+6mf3no39ua+rDQ==">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    <input class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Email Id / Mobile No" type="text" name="session[username]">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    <input class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Passowrd" type="password" name="session[password]">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button name="authenicatebtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-login">Login</button>
            </div>
```

It is a ajax request to the server when i view in the networks tab its showing `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` error.

Answer (score 0):

From the Rails doc:

> **:authenticity_token** - Authenticity token to use in the form. Use only if you need to pass custom authenticity token string, or to not add authenticity_token field at all (by passing false).
>
> ... Remote forms get the authenticity token from the meta tag, so embedding is unnecessary unless you support browsers without JavaScript.

What are you trying to achieve by passing `:authenticity_token => true` in your form?